# C# creating a dictionary of objects with generics applied

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary

I have a class structure like this:

```
public class BaseDataType
{
    //... some properties
}


public class FirstCustomDataType : BaseDataType
{
    //...some more properties
}


public class SecondCustomDataType : BaseDataType
{
    //...some more properties
}


public interface IMonitor<T> where T : BaseDataType
{
    List<List<DataSample<T>>> GetData();
}


public abstract class GenericMonitor<T> : IMonitor<T> where T : BaseDataType 
{
    protected List<List<DataSample<T>>> Data { get; set; }

    public List<List<DataSample<T>>> GetData() { return Data; }
}


public class FirstNonGenericMonitor : GenericMonitor<FirstCustomDataType> { }


public class SecondNonGenericMonitor : GenericMonitor<SecondCustomDataType> { }
```

Now I would like to have a dictionary, that will hold all my non generic monitors:

```
Dictionary< ResourceToMonitorEnum, IMonitor<BaseDataType> > Monitors
```

However, I don't know how should I add a new monitor to this dictionary, because this:

```
Monitors.Add( ResourceToMonitorEnum.Monitor1, new FirstNonGenericMonitor() )
```

won't let me add new FirstNonGenericMonitor as the IMonitor< T > because the types don't match. I know that it's the type issue but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: why do you even need such complex inheritance? i think you are picking a wrong way to what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your `FirstGenericMonitor` instance as a `IMonitor<BaseDataType>` like so:

```
Monitors.Add(ResourceToMonitorEnum, new FirstNonGenericMonitor() as IMonitor<BaseDataType>);
```

Echoing M.kazem Akhgary's comment, this does seem to be a pretty complicated inheritance model you have here.  It's worth considering if all of this is truly necessary, or if you are needlessly introducing complexity.